# JQuery dynamically changed 'Attribute Contains' selector doesn't work with var

Tags: jquery, string, variables, dynamic, selector

I have an element that has an ID that *starts* with "mn" and is of class "elementSubMenuTitle" created like so:

```
$("#mn"+j).append("<p id='mn"+j+"rpt"+i+"' 
class='elementSubMenuTitle'>"+reportList[i].ReportName+"</p>");
```

If I use a jquery selector of `$("[id^='mn0']+.elementSubMenuTitle")`, it can find my first element (mn0rpt0), however I need it to be able to loop through an unknown number of these elements which follow a pattern of mn0rpt0, mn0rpt1, mn1rpt2, etc.
Using

```
var x = String(0); 
$("[id^=mn"+x+"]+.elementSubMenuTitle").stop(true,true).fadeOut(200);
```

works to find "mn0.." but obviously I need to find also "mn1.." and the others, so I tried:

```
for(var i = 0; i < catList.length; i++) 
{
var x = String(i);
$("[id^=mn"+x+"]+.elementSubMenuTitle").stop(true,true).fadeOut(200);
}
```

but this approach doesn't work.
So why is String(0) making a string, while String(i) does not?  (At least that's my theory)

To elaborate:
There are parent elements that follow the nomenclature
mn0
mn1
mn2
mn3
..
These themselves are setup by a loop.

There are child elements that begin with mn0 if is a child of mn0, for example mn0rpt0 is a child of mn0, but is not the only child.  The children that I'm interested in specifically have the class `elementSubMenuTitle` and also begin with mn0.  Same goes for mn1 and it's children, etc.

The purpose of the loop is to set specific behavior for the set of children of "mnx".  That behavior will vary based on x.  For example, $(child of mnx) will need to be placed (x*30) pixels below $(child of mn(x-1)), etc.  Therefore the x is necessary, and thereby the loop.

Ultimately, I am asking why `var x = String(i)` does not work while `var x = String(0)` does, when inserted into $("[id^=mn"+x+"]+.elementSubMenuTitle")

Comment: Is `$("[id^='mn']")` not sufficient?

Comment: @j08691: what if you had `<div id="mnemonic">` on the page elsewhere? :) Yes, the class should be added to a *starts-with selector* in this instance (and was requested explicitly). If it were a single ID match, *then* the class would be obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [attribute *starts with*](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector: `[attr^=value]`

You do not need the loop at all:

```
$("[id^=mn].elementSubMenuTitle").stop(true,true).fadeOut(200);
```

Obviously you no longer need to string together a selector, so the `+` is not needed either. This translates literally to your requirement of

> an ID that starts with "mn" and is of class "elementSubMenuTitle"

Comment: IMO adding the class is irrelevant since IDs are (or rather should be) unique.

Comment: @j08691: Your opinion does not take into account other ids starting with `mn`. This is not a single match :) The question is very clear that `an ID that starts with "mn" and is of class "elementSubMenuTitle" `

Comment: +1 also for removing the `+` in the selector. Maybe you should explain it

Comment: @Brewal: The `+` was only there to string together the elements around their index value. As they already knew to do that I assumed they know what is does, but I will elaborate :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie: At this point I'm not necessarily worried whether it starts with, or contains "mn", as long as it is one or the other; I realize the difference between ^ and * here.  Really, though, I need it to "start with" so I will use ^.  Thanks for letting me know I needed to clear that up.